# doesn't work .buttonset() on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, wordpress-theming

I have a number of :checkbox elements that are initialized by a wordpress.
Now i set .buttonset() function to #format but this is not work...
like this sample:http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

HTML:

```
<div id="format">
    <?php
     $categories = get_categories();
     foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>">
     <label><?php echo $category->cat_name;?></label><?php } ?>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#format').buttonset();
$('input[type=checkbox]').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden-accessible');

$(':checkbox[name=check]').each(function( i ){
    var nameID = 'check'+ (i+1);
    this.id = nameID;
    $(this).next('label').prop('for', nameID); 
});
```

Comment: are you getting any errors.. check you console

Comment: is code wrapped in `document.ready`?

Comment: @bipen with firebug there is no error

Comment: explanation of `doesn't work` isn't much to go on. Did you include jQuery UI css?

Comment: @charlietfl YES I'M SURE...

Answer (score 0):

All your checkboxes has the same name "check".
Try to do this:

```
<div id="format">
    <?php
     $i = 0;
     $categories = get_categories();
     foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>">
     <label><?php echo $category->cat_name;?></label>
     <?php 
       $i++;
       } 
      ?>
</div>
```

Then in your js:

```
$(':checkbox[name^=check]').each(function( i ){
    var nameID = 'check'+ (i+1);
    this.id = nameID;
    $(this).next('label').prop('for', nameID); 
});
```

Then jQuery will find all checkboxes that start with name check, like "check1", "checkblabla", etc...

And the "$('#format').buttonset();" needs to come after the "for" change.
Fonts:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Edited:

I think you dont really need to change the for with js, you can do that only with php, then:

```
<div id="format">
    <?php
     $i = 0;
     $categories = get_categories();
     foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>">
     <label for="check<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $category->cat_name;?></label>
     <?php 
       $i++;
       } 
      ?>
</div>
```

Then in your js:

```
$( "#format" ).buttonset();
```

Comment: The second solution didnt work? Could you copy me the html that is generated?

Comment: You forget about this line "<input type="checkbox" name="check<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>">" The name needs to be name="check<?php echo $i ?>". The generated html should look like this: <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="3" class="" id="check1">. Im talking about the second solution.

Comment: generated code is matches... but still doesn't work.... if i add this code : `<input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label for="check1">B</label>`  it's work well...